# Identify streak in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have data in resdshift with the following structure:

```sql
create table streak(id int, user int, category char);

insert into streak values(1, 1, 'A');
insert into streak values(2, 1, 'B');
insert into streak values(3, 1, 'A');
insert into streak values(4, 1, 'B');
insert into streak values(5, 1, 'B');

insert into streak values(6, 2, 'A');
insert into streak values(7, 2, 'A');
insert into streak values(8, 2, 'B');
insert into streak values(9, 2, 'B');
insert into streak values(10,2, 'B');

insert into streak values(11,3, 'B');
insert into streak values(12,3, 'A');

select * from streak
```

I want, for each user, to have, both:

- the longest streak of B's
- the length of the streak of B's until the last record

In this case, we would have something like:

```
user|longest_streak|last_streak
1|2|2
2|3|3
3|1|0
```

How can I do that in redshift?

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: honestly I have no idea, I was thinking about window functions but don't know how I would go about them in this case

Comment: lookup "gaps and islands"